# How to validate sip incoming and outgoing URL for twilio sip trunk

Tags: twilio, sip

I am using freepbx to connect to twilio elastic sip trunk. Which domain for incoming and outgoing URL to be used and how to authenticate it ?

Can I use softphone like eyebeam or x-lite to make call s ? What would be codec value ?

Comment: Add question related code here

Comment: Check out the documentation here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/getting-started#your-network